# How to get URL without file extension using DirectoryMatch

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I want it so that all URL requests without a ".php" extension are handled by the appropriate .php file, and still be able to name those files with the ".php" extension.

```
<DirectoryMatch "/var/www/html">   #This works for the one directory
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule "^(\w+)$" "$1.php"
</DirectoryMatch>
```

This is what should work for all subdirectories:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^(/var/www/htm).*">    #This does not work
```

Here's a list of things I've tried that I thought should all be the same but aren't:

```
<DirectoryMatch "/var/www/html">     #this works
<DirectoryMatch /var/www/html>       #this works 
<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/html">    #"The requested URL was not found on this server."
<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/html$">   #"The requested URL was not found on this server."
<DirectoryMatch "^(/var/www/html)$"> #"The requested URL was not found on this server."
<DirectoryMatch "^(/var/www/htm).*"> #"The requested URL was not found on this server."
```

It seems as soon as I actually use regular expressions, it no longer works.  However, the regular expression in the rewrite rule does work.

Why isn't the regex working for DirectoryMatch?

Here's some things to help you test your answer:

```
<?php
if(!($code=@$_GET["code"])){echo 'no code in GET';exit;}
else {$code=$_GET["code"];}
echo 'Success, code is: '.$code;
?>

https://yoursite.com/test/testing?code=testcode

sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Comment: consider remove ^

Comment: I didn't list every single thing I tried, and I tried for a while. Please try it yourself and respond if you confirm your solution.  Thanks

Comment: no resorse can not